# imagemagick %d not working on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal, imagemagick

My goal is to split a PNG image file in two equals parts. (vertical split)
I found this command on some website:

```
convert -crop 50%x100% +repage 1.png out_%d.png
```

The problem is that the %d doesn't seems to work. The output is only one file named "out_%d.png" instead of "out_0.png" and "out_1.png".

I am running this command from a terminal in Ubuntu 14.04.
Any idea why the %d is not working ?

Comment: Your command works OK on OS X / bash / ImageMagick 6.9.0-0 Q16 x86_64 2015-01-25.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I did an update of the imagemagick package and after it was OK. It was probably a bug in the software itself. My command to update the package was: sudo apt-get install imagemagick